# Installing laravel using Zend Server 8.0.1 PHP 5.6.4 CLI stopped working

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, zend-server, php-5.6

I have Installed ***Zend Server 8.0.1*** with ***PHP 5.6.4*** on ***Windows 8.1***. I have added '***E:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin***' to PATH variable, which contains PHP binaries.

I have Installed Composer Globally. I am trying to create a Laravel project using composer command '***composer create-project laravel/laravel***'. After a while PHP CLI stops working. Screen shot is below.
[image]
screen shot of PHP settings given below.[image]
I tried it few times but same error. Has anybody faced same problem. Unfortunately I don't have tool to analyze Dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug with Zend Server 8.x, PHP 5.6 and composer running on Windows that Zend is aware of (see http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&p=245953).

Using older version of composer.phar works for me. Get the composer.phar from the Zend Skeleton Application (https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) and  try with it.

Comment: Thanks Emil. At first I wondered why Zend forum link, you shared in your answer, did not turn up in my googling. But I realized it was posted on Mar 04, 2015 , much later then  my question on stackoverflow.